# Using template literal within JSON objects in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have API data in my React component. It's in the form of

```
{weather.Wind.Speed.Metric.Value}
```

Is there any way I can swap Metric out for a variable such as unit.

For example something like

```
const unit = 'Metric';

{weather.Wind.Speed.${unit}.Value}
```

That way I can update the variable and show the correct data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bracket notation: `weather.Wind.Speed[unit].Value`.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors